# AskUbuntu tells me I'm in danger of being blocked

Tags: support

When I wanted to ask a question on AskUbuntu, I got a warning that states "Some of your past questions have not been well-received".

Here I interpret "some" as "at least one", but I cannot really interpret "have not been well-received", as this is very loose. While I received the Mad Max movie well, my grandma did not.

I have 2 questions on the AskUbuntu site, with 1/0 reputation, and 3 answers with 2/0/0 rep. The upvoted question got a downvote.
All these answering/questioning/upvoting/downvoting happened in 2011 and 2013, I am mainly a reader on AskUbuntu.

Is this a real threat so I will be blocked, or is this just a bug?

I have never encountered this warning message on other StackExchange sites.

Comment: Any deleted questions? Downvotes on deleted questions also count for this metric.

Comment: I could only check "recent" deleted questions, but found none. I checked the Reputation tab, as it seemed accurate (http://askubuntu.com/users/12321/karatedog?tab=reputation)

Comment: The "Reputation" tab is not accurate for this purpose, as it doesn't report reputation variations for deleted questions / answers, which as muru said are relevant in this case

Comment: So, there is no proper way to find out what _might_ cause this warning, and the math behind the algorithm is not public.